Does this sequence ever end?
This may help: A080670 A195265
Define $f(n)$ as this:
Take a number $n$, and split it into its prime composition using $^$ and $×$. Now remove all $^$ and $×$, you get a new number, this is $f(n)$ (Example: $f(20)=225$ because $20$=$2$^$2$×$5$ and $f(13)=13$ because $13=13$)
Now repeat $f(n)$, does it ever repeat or become prime?
The answer is yes for every number under $20$, but if you do start with $20$, you get numbers over:
$$7619860311238375857894724798334256170952046407785111199930594835524474243089$$
I spent over half an hour determining if this sequence ever ends, and I haven't found any solution. If this ever ends, do other sequences like this don't?

Just to make sure that the sequence is precisely defined: You take the prime decomposition, order the occuring primes increasingly from left to right, omit the exponent 1 whenever it occurs, and of course 1 itself is not a prime number. Furthermore you work in base 10 (which also could affect the result).

3 votes to close as not research level? Is this question trivial for experts with the relevant knowledge base? It doesn't look trivial to me, but I have no expertise in this area.

@AlecRhea there lacks a reason to close that sounds more like "this is probably hard, but not a problem that would be considered a serious question by researchers". In number theory there are many such examples: take your favourite arithmetic sequence and take your favourite polynomial and you can ask: does this polynomial take on infinitely many values from that arithmetic sequence? One cannot consider ALL such questions interesting.

@StanleyYaoXiao But should we be closing questions just because 'most research mathematicians in that field wouldn't be interested in this problem'?  What people are interested in (even active researchers in a given field) doesn't dictate what is and isn't mathematics, nor does it determine what is/isn't research level imo. For a really extreme example, most of Cantor's contemporaries were uninterested in his work.

@AlecRhea sure, I didn't vote to close, just to say that problems of this sort are easy to generate and usually go nowhere. Number theorists in particular have to be vigilant about catching "mathematical diseases" (Tim Gowers used this phrase to describe the Collatz conjecture, which is actually somewhat reminiscent of this question), i.e., getting stuck thinking about a simple-sounding problem that ultimately goes nowhere.

@StanleyYaoXiao: It is a question out of curiosity. Mathematics should be open for such questions.

I think moverflow should be open to it too! I will defend slightly @AlecRhea 's point in that its very easy to make hard questions by mixing string manipulation with elementary number theory. Despite that I think it's good to allow these in the sense that I don't think this will get answered today. But 200 years from now we might ask "what are all the questions on early mathoverflow using basic arithmetic and string manipulation that we haven't resolved yet" and this can end up on a list sorted by "complexity" and eventually hacking at it can prove to be useful.

Picking one such question and obsessing over it might be very dangerous for reasons identical to the Collatz Conjecture being described as a mathematical disease. I don't know for sure but I'm sure there are a lot of "easy to state" questions that are going to require techniques beyond ANYTHING that has been invented or will be invented for centuries to come in order to crack. And that's the reality of it.

$2^59^2=2592$, as noted by Dudeney. Alas, $9$ isn't a prime.

$13532385396179 = 13·53^2·3853·96179$, This apparently is the smallest number that $f(n)=n$

@StanleyYaoXiao We can all be grateful that John Conway chose to ignore the conventional wisdom about what professional mathematicians are "supposed to" work on, and instead carved out his own path.

@TimothyChow sure, but not all of us (in fact, few if any) are John Conway

@StanleyYaoXiao I agree that less talented mathematicians must take fewer risks when it comes to their career, but my point is that it is not true that research mathematicians, even those of the caliber of Conway, necessarily consider such questions to be "not serious." Maybe the problem goes nowhere, but maybe it doesn't. One can't be sure of such things ahead of time. Any individual mathematician may choose, for whatever combination of reasons, not to work on a particular problem, but that doesn't necessarily mean there's anything wrong with the problem itself.

I think of the situation as akin to a multi-armed bandit problem. Do I explore by pulling on the Collatz-palindrome-aliquot-etc arm, or do I exploit by pulling on the current-hot-topic arm? My expectation is that the optimal strategy involves occasional exploration. Gauss refused to pull on the Fermat's-last-theorem arm, which is fine, but luckily for us some other people did pull on that arm.

Does this answer your question? Implications of the disproof of the "climb-to-a-prime" conjecture

This is John H. Conway's Climb to a prime problem. Conway originally conjectured that no matter what number you start with, you will eventually converge to a prime. This conjecture was disproven by James Davis, who found a composite number that is a fixed point.
That 20 is not known to converge was noticed very quickly after Conway first asked the question, but Conway still believed it would eventually converge.
One could ask if there are any heuristic arguments for or against the conjecture; I don't know of any published analysis.

Probably an interesting question is why it seems that with base $2$ instead of $10$ and the same procedure, we get large primes: (Notice that for $d=2$ the starting number $20$ gets a prime).
def ff(n,d=10):
    ll = []
    for p in sorted(prime_divisors(n)):
        dd = Integer(p).digits(d)
        dd.reverse()
        ll.extend(dd)
        if valuation(n,p)>1:
            dd = Integer(valuation(n,p)).digits(d)
            dd.reverse()
            ll.extend(dd)
    return sum(ll[len(ll)-1-i]*d**i for i in range(len(ll)))

def iter_ff(n,k,d):
    if k==0:
        return n
    else:
        return ff(iter_ff(n,k-1,d),d)

x = 2**2*5       
while not is_prime(Integer(x)):
    x = ff(x,d=2)
    print(x)    
    
maxIter = 55    
for d in range(2,11):
     for n in range(2,100):
        x = n
        i = 0
        while not is_prime(Integer(x)) and i < maxIter:
            x = ff(x,d=d)
            print("base = ",d,"starting number = ",n,"current number = ",x,"iteration count = ", i+1)
            i+=1
        #print(d,n,iter_ff(n,k,d),is_prime(Integer(iter_ff(n,k,d))))

        

Output:
85
177
251
base =  2 starting number =  4 current number =  10 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  4 current number =  21 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  4 current number =  31 iteration count =  3
base =  2 starting number =  6 current number =  11 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  8 current number =  11 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  9 current number =  14 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  9 current number =  23 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  10 current number =  21 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  10 current number =  31 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  12 current number =  43 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  14 current number =  23 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  15 current number =  29 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  16 current number =  20 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  16 current number =  85 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  16 current number =  177 iteration count =  3
base =  2 starting number =  16 current number =  251 iteration count =  4
base =  2 starting number =  18 current number =  46 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  18 current number =  87 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  18 current number =  125 iteration count =  3
base =  2 starting number =  18 current number =  23 iteration count =  4
base =  2 starting number =  20 current number =  85 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  20 current number =  177 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  20 current number =  251 iteration count =  3
base =  2 starting number =  21 current number =  31 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  22 current number =  43 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  24 current number =  47 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  25 current number =  22 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  25 current number =  43 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  26 current number =  45 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  26 current number =  117 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  26 current number =  237 iteration count =  3
base =  2 starting number =  26 current number =  463 iteration count =  4
base =  2 starting number =  27 current number =  15 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  27 current number =  29 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  28 current number =  87 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  28 current number =  125 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  28 current number =  23 iteration count =  3
base =  2 starting number =  30 current number =  93 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  30 current number =  127 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  32 current number =  21 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  32 current number =  31 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  33 current number =  59 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  34 current number =  81 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  34 current number =  28 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  34 current number =  87 iteration count =  3
base =  2 starting number =  34 current number =  125 iteration count =  4
base =  2 starting number =  34 current number =  23 iteration count =  5
base =  2 starting number =  35 current number =  47 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  36 current number =  174 iteration count =  1
base =  2 starting number =  36 current number =  381 iteration count =  2
base =  2 starting number =  36 current number =  511 iteration count =  3 

For $n=217$ and for $d=2$ you get as an example a cycle which is not a prime:
SageMath-Script
$$217, 255, 945, 1007, 1269,1007,1269,1007\ldots$$
